# Cupy is slower than numpy at emulating dot product with one hot vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cupy

I was trying to implement neural network from scratch. However it is not possible to run numpy on GPU. So I tried using cupy and benchmarking performance improvement over numpy.

I have following code in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

emb = 300  # embedding size
m = 2048   # minibatch size
V = 50000  # vocabulary size

# generate 100 random one hot vectors
J = np.random.choice(emb, m) 
X = np.zeros((m, emb))
for i, j in enumerate(J):
    X[i, j] = 1

W0 = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (V, emb)).astype("float32") 

# actual computation
start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(5):
  for mb in range(314): # number of minibatches per epoch
    h = np.zeros((1), dtype='float32')
    for xi in X.T: 
        w0i = np.argmax(xi)
        if not h.any(): h = W0[w0i]
        else: h = np.vstack((h, W0[w0i]))
print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The `actual computation` part takes 16.55 seconds.

I converted above code into cupy equivalent by simply replacing numpy with cupy

```
import cupy as cp

# generate 100 random one hot vectors 
J = cp.random.choice(emb, m) 
X = cp.zeros((m, emb))
for i, j in enumerate(J):
    X[i, j] = 1

W0 = cp.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (V, emb)).astype("float32") # V⨯e

# actual computation 
start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(5):
  for mb in range(314): # minibatches
    h = cp.zeros((1), dtype='float32')
    for xi in X.T: # m times
        w0i = cp.argmax(xi)
        if not h.any(): h = W0[w0i] # (1xe) 
        else: h = cp.vstack((h, W0[w0i]))
print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The `actual computation` part took 2 min 32 seconds (total 152.15 seconds) to execute. I was expecting it to take far lesser time than numpy. But it did not. What I am missing here?

**PS:**

1. You can access the corresponding colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18BA91hyjImDz8sixTrp_II8Recbh42Bh?usp=sharing).
2. cupy comes pre-installed in GPU runtime of google colab.
3. What I am trying to do with that computation?
   Actually, I am trying reduce matrix dot product computation time. Above every column of `X` is one hot vector. So multiply it by any matrix (`W0` above) has effect of selecting row of a matrix corresponding to position where one hot vector has 1. So, I am trying to iterate through each vector of X, find position of `1` in the vector and fetch corresponding row from `W0` and stack them for all `m` vectors in `X`. Here is the example for one vector [[ref](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#Review-on-Word2Vec-Skip-Gram)]:

[image]

4. The linked colab notebook shows `np.dot` takes 1518.75 seconds while numpy emulation of dot product takes 16.55 seconds. So, numpy emulation is indeed faster than `np.dot`, but I was expecting cupy on GPU to be even faster, but this is not the case. It takes 152.15 seconds.
5. The linked colab notebook also shows how the emulation produces same result as `np.dot` with smaller matrices.

Comment: I think you made some mistakes on your code though. And even if you didn't, why would that automatically make cupy faster than numpy?
Your one hot encoding makes one-hot vectors in rows, not columns for example.
And I don't quite get the for loops. argmax is better done when you compute it on the whole vector. Why is it inside the for loop?

Comment: Yeah I think your shapes are just wrong, you have a transpose where I think it shouldn't be, and it just does not match to your ref link. I recommend going through the numpy calculation step by step to figure out your shapes, and your indexing.

Comment: Your for loop can be replaced with something similar to this:
w0index = np.argmax(X, axis=1);
W0[w0index]

No need for vstack. It's inefficient to pack more and more data to a numpy array, if you can avoid it. If you must have vstack with for loop, than first put it into python list, then stack them together at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you perform GPU operations operating at a **too small granularity**. Indeed, GPUs are made to compute **massively parallel** operations and are clearly not designed for low-latency. Starting a GPU kernel has a significant overhead taking generally at least few microseconds (actually, often few dozens of µs). Allocating input and output data also add some overhead on top of that, not to mention the overhead of using CuPy compared to Numpy. With a sequential time of 16.55 seconds on CPU, each iteration of the xi-based loop should take in average `16.55/5/314/300 = 35 µs`. This is definitively too small for a GPU kernel, especially since you expect the GPU time to be significantly smaller than that while the overhead is close to this time. You should operate at a heavier granularity to benefit from any GPU speed-up. Using `np.argmax(X, axis=1)` should significantly help.

Moreover, GPUs are quite inefficient on **strided** arrays (`X.T` is not contiguous), like CPUs actually. This is more critical on GPU though mainly because the SIMD execution is what makes them fast and operating on stridded input is generally not SIMD-friendly. Using better vectorized operation can help CuPy to generate a fast code operating on contiguous dimentions.

In addition, having `h = np.vstack((h, W0[w0i]))` in a loop is known to be an anti-pattern. Indeed, this create a new **temporary array** for each iteration resulting in a **quadratic execution**. This is even worst on GPUs due to the additional latency. You should never do that. Instead, you should *pre-allocate* the array and fill it. Even better : use a vectorized operation to create the array directly when this is possible. Otherwise, writing your own kernel can also be a good idea for sake of performance.